Spotify API in Flutter twitching/flashing and doesnt let me move forward
I am currently testing something out with the Spotify API with Android SDK and once I click a button, it brings me out of the flutter app into google where I try to authenticate
But before I authenticate, while spotify is opening on the browser, it starts to twitch and glitch and doesn't let me continue.
here 1
here2
Not sure how to move forward since i Couldn;t find anything online
